# no-unused-expressions error in package.json

Tags: eslint

I am adding a linter to my big existing project. I have enabled "error" for `no-unused-expressions`. I am using [lint-staged](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged) to run the linter upon git committing.

my `.lintstagedrc.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  '*': ['eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx,.graphql --fix .', 'npx prettier --ignore-path .eslintignore --write'],
}
```

When trying to git commit (staging includes changes to `package.json`)

I get:

```
/Users/myuser/myproject/package.json
  1:1  error  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

And my normal-looking `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "private": true,
  "description": "myproject description",
...
```

Since `json` is such a tightly defined format, I have a high degree of confidence it is formatted properly. This leads me to believe it is an `eslint` setting of some sort. I can't even really be sure why this `no-unused-expressions` rule would be looking at a `json` file.

Not sure where to begin diagnosing this one.

Comment: Why are you trying to call eslint on `package.json`?

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad actually I am not directly; I was trying to make a minimally reducible example, but now realize that I left out key info. In fact, I am running `eslint` only on staged files, by using [lint-staged](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged). This error above occurs when I try to commit. I'm updating the question to include my `.lintstagedrc.js`

Comment: Obviously some part of your config makes eslint check `package.json` as well. If you can't figure out where exactly this is coming from, your other option is to disallow `*.json` files in `.eslintignore`.

Comment: Actually the problem might be the `'*'` inside your `.lintstagedrc.js`. How about replacing it with `'*.{js, jsx, ts, tsx, graphql}': ['eslint --fix']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'*'` in your `.lintstagedrc.js` means all files will be checked by eslint, regardless of extension. What you probably want to do is this:

```
module.exports = {
  '*.{js, jsx, ts, tsx, graphql}': ['eslint --fix', 'prettier --ignore-path .eslintignore --write'],
}
```

By calling eslint on `package.json` you interpret it as a JavaScript/TypeScript file (based on your configuration). Any JSON file is also a valid JavaScript file that contains a single value that is not assigned to anything, which is called an [unused expression](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions) and should not normally occur in your code.